# ¿Cómo podría encontrar la posición de un número en un array de tipo int definido?

Tags: java, array

podrían ayudarme con esta duda

//Atributo privado de tipo array o arreglo lineal

```
private int[] edad= {27, 22, 13, 12, 25, 11, 29, 70, 15, 21};
```

Lo que hice fue

```
public int posUltimaEdadAdolescente() {

        for(int i=0;i<tamaño();i++)
            if(edad[i]<=20 && (edad[i]>=12))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
```

Debido a que me pide que retorne la posición del ultimo número encontrado en el rango de 12 a 20 años y en caso no exista un -1  pero al ejecutarlo me tira posición 2 es decir 13

Psdt: el tamaño es

```
public int tamaño() {

        return edad.length;//10
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Recorre el arreglo de forma inversa y te funcionará.

Comment: @Lobos Buenas bro al recorrerlo por el ultimo me dio la posición 8 y esta bien , pero mi otra duda es al querer aplicar esta condición. Un método que retorne la posición de la primera edad encontrada en el rango de 12 a 20 años. es decir cuenta la edad 12? por que si fuera así tendría que devolverme la posición 4 según el arreglo cierto?

Comment: la primera edad entre 12-20 seria 13 , la menor edad entre 12-20 seria 12

Comment: Si pones un return dentro del if, se saldrá en cuanto encuentras el primer número que entra al if... si buscas el último, no puedes usar return, debes almacenar su posición (`i`) en una variable y cuando terminas de recorrer el array lo devuelves.

Comment: @Dramaturgo mmm :0 entonces cuando es array al poner la condición edad[i]>=12 && edad[i]<=20 y recorrera del 0,1,2,3,4 y el primero que encuentre en este caso 13 y 12 en la posición 4  , me devolvera 13 y cumple la condición pero importa más la posición?

Comment: el bucle recorrera todas las posiciones pero al poner return dentro de la condicional if te devolvera el primer indice  que cumpla la condicional en tu caso i=2 evitando que el bucle recorra los demás indices,recuerda que los indices parten de 0,12 se encuentra en la posición 3

Comment: @Dramaturgo claro , mira yo no le puse {} al if solo al método, asi public int posPrimeraAdolescente() {
  for(int i=0;i<tamaño();i++) 
   if(edad[i]>=12 && edad[i]<=20)
    return i;
  return -1;
 }
Y pongo return por que el metodo me pide que retorne algo de tipo int

Comment: el uso de llaves es opcional cuando dentro de la condición hay una sola linea de codigo ,personalmente te recomiendo usar llaves y para obtener lo que buscas sin aplicar bucle inverso ,usa una variable como lo indica benito `int ultimo=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<edad.length;i++)
            if(edad[i]<=20 && (edad[i]>=12)){
                ultimo=i;
            }
        return ultimo;
    }`

Comment: @Dramaturgo bro mira lo aplique mencionando lo que dijiste , pero no se como aplicarlo en esta foto https://prnt.sc/dm-G1lA9pUC1

Comment: están bien aplicados,que problema tenes?

Comment: @Dramaturgo aaa espera espera lo que menciono Benito y tu sobre poner el ultimaEdad=-1; solo se aplica para hallar el ultimo numero que coincida con la condición que le puse , pero para hallar el primer esta bien ponerle return?

Comment: exacto bro lee con pausa lo que se ah comentado y le atinaras, y si estas usando un IDE aprende a usar la herramienta debug

Comment: mmm valeeee ya lo entendí , muchas gracias bro :D

Answer (score 1):

Caso : ultima posicion de la edad en el rango 12 - 20

```
public int posUltimaEdadAdolescente() {
    int pos = -1;
   for(int i=0;i<tamaño();i++)
       if(edad[i]<=20 && (edad[i]>=12))
           pos = i;
    return pos;
}
```

Caso : primera posicion del primer numero en el rango de edad 12 - 20

```
public int posUltimaEdadAdolescente() {
   int pos = -1;
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       if(edad[i]<=20 && (edad[i]>=12))
           return pos = i;
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).